# AndroidStudio: Unable to start activity (ViewModel not found)

Tags: android-studio

I'm encountering the 'ViewModel Not Found' error when launching my Android Activity. I've checked ViewModelFactory, Repository, and Manifest registration, but the issue persists. Any suggestions on how to identify the root cause of the problem? this activity is used to show questions and answers taken from an api on the screen.

that's the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.devquiz, PID: 7664
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.devquiz/com.example.devquiz.view.ExerciseActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ViewModel Not Found
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8176)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ViewModel Not Found
                                                                                                        at com.example.devquiz.viewmodel.ExerciseViewModelFactory.create(ExerciseViewModelFactory.kt:13)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:83)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
                                                                                                        at com.example.devquiz.view.ExerciseActivity.onCreate(ExerciseActivity.kt:32)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8176) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

that's my activity:

```
class ExerciseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityExerciseBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: ExerciseViewModel
    private val retrofitService = APIService.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityExerciseBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ExerciseViewModelFactory(ExerciseRepository(retrofitService))).get(ExerciseViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val intent = intent
        var languageType = intent.getStringExtra("type")


        if (languageType != null) {
            binding.typeLenguageTextview.text = languageType
            viewModel.getTypeOfExercise(languageType)
            viewModel.getExercise()
            initExercise()
        } else{
            //Implementar Exceções
        }
        updateQuestionNumber()
        verifyAPIError()
        onButtonCloseClick()
    }

    private fun updateQuestionNumber() {
        viewModel.currencyQuestion.observe(this, Observer {
            binding.questionNumber.text = it.toString()
        })
    }

    private fun verifyAPIError(){
        viewModel.errorSignal.observe(this, Observer {
            if (it == 1) {
                //Implementar Exceções
            }
        })
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    private fun initExercise() {
        viewModel.exercise.observe(this, Observer { exercise ->
            val button1 = binding.buttonOption1
            val button2 = binding.buttonOption2
            val button3 = binding.buttonOption3

            button1.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
            button2.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
            button3.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

            button1.isEnabled = true
            button2.isEnabled = true
            button3.isEnabled = true

            val randomNumber = generateRandomNumber()

            binding.questionText.text = exercise.question

            if (randomNumber <= 300){
                button1.text = exercise.options[0]
                button2.text = exercise.options[1]
                button3.text = exercise.options[2]
            }

            if (randomNumber in 301..600){
                button1.text = exercise.options[1]
                button2.text = exercise.options[0]
                button3.text = exercise.options[2]
            }

            if (randomNumber > 600){
                button1.text = exercise.options[2]
                button2.text = exercise.options[1]
                button3.text = exercise.options[0]
            }

            button1.setOnClickListener {
                button2.isEnabled = false
                button3.isEnabled = false
                if (button1.text == exercise.options[0]) {
                    button1.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.yellow))
                    playCorrectAnswerSound()
                    getNewExerciseWithDelay()
                } else {
                    button1.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.red))
                    vibrate()
                    getNewExerciseWithDelay()
                }
            }

            button2.setOnClickListener {
                button1.isEnabled = false
                button3.isEnabled = false
                if (button2.text == exercise.options[0]) {
                    button2.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.yellow))
                    playCorrectAnswerSound()
                    getNewExerciseWithDelay()
                } else {
                    button2.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.red))
                    vibrate()
                    getNewExerciseWithDelay()
                }
            }

            button3.setOnClickListener {
                button1.isEnabled = false
                button2.isEnabled = false
                if (button3.text == exercise.options[0]) {
                    button3.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.yellow))
                    playCorrectAnswerSound()
                    getNewExerciseWithDelay()
                } else {
                    button3.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.red))
                    vibrate()
                    getNewExerciseWithDelay()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun getNewExerciseWithDelay(){
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            viewModel.getExercise()
        }, 250)
    }

    private fun onButtonCloseClick() {
        binding.closeButton.setOnClickListener{
            finish()
        }
    }

    private fun generateRandomNumber(): Int {
        return (0..1000).random()
    }

    private fun playCorrectAnswerSound(){
        val correctAnswerMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.correctansweraudio)

        if (correctAnswerMediaPlayer.isPlaying){
            correctAnswerMediaPlayer.stop()
        }
        correctAnswerMediaPlayer.start()
    }

    private fun vibrate(){
        val vibrate = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 26){
            vibrate.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(100, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE))
        } else {
            vibrate.vibrate(100)
        }
    }
}
```

that's my viewmodel:

```
class ExerciseViewModel(private val exerciseRepository: ExerciseRepository): ViewModel() {

    var exercise = MutableLiveData<ExerciseModel>()
    var errorSignal = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)
    var typeLanguage = ""
    var currencyQuestion = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)

    fun getTypeOfExercise(type: String){
        typeLanguage = type
    }

    fun getExercise() {
        when (typeLanguage) {
            "Phyton" -> getPhytonExercise()
            "Javascript" -> getJavascriptExercise()
            "C" -> getCExercise()
            "Java" -> getJavaExercise()
            "C++" -> getCPlusExercise()
            "C#" -> getCSharpExercise()
            "Ruby" -> getRubyExercise()
            "Swift" -> getSwiftExercise()
            "Php" -> getPhpExercise()
            "Web" -> getHtmlAndCssExercise()
            "Go" -> getGoExercise()
            "Kotlin" -> getKotlinExercise()
            "Rust" -> getRustExercise()
            "Typescript" -> getTypescriptExercise()
            "Sql" -> getSQLExercise()
        }
    }

    private fun getPhytonExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getPhytonExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getJavascriptExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getJavascriptExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getCExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getCExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getJavaExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getJavaExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getCPlusExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getCPlusExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getCSharpExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getCSharpExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getRubyExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getRubyExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getSwiftExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getSwiftExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getPhpExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getPhpExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getHtmlAndCssExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getHtmlAndCssExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getGoExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getGoExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getKotlinExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getKotlinExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getRustExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getRustExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getTypescriptExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getTypescriptExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun getSQLExercise() {
        exerciseRepository.getSQLExercises().enqueue(createCallback())
    }

    private fun createCallback(): Callback<ExerciseModel> {
        return object : Callback<ExerciseModel> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ExerciseModel>, response: Response<ExerciseModel>) {
                exercise.postValue(response.body())
                currencyQuestion.postValue(currencyQuestion.value?.plus(1))
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ExerciseModel>, t: Throwable) {
                errorSignal.postValue(1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and that's the viewmodelFactory:

```
class ExerciseViewModelFactory constructor(private val exerciseRepository: ExerciseRepository): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ExerciseModel::class.java)) {
            ExerciseViewModel(this.exerciseRepository) as T
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("ViewModel Not Found")
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me on this, i'll be very grateful.